# Why appear input_Login is undefined from browser?

Tags: javascript

I have simple program here. It works, but still appear error in browser input_Login is undefined, why? I don't understand it, please help.

```
var input_Login = document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];


function inputCheck(){
    this.style.color='pink';
}

input_Login.addEventListener('input', inputCheck);
```

Comment: Do you run that code in the head of your page?

Comment: No but it does not metter. The problem is with error input_Login is undefined. But this var has definision in code.

Comment: Yeah, it would matter

Comment: Problem is the same, after run it in the head of page.